# REACT:Help conditionally rendering btn

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> I cant get a button to show "shortlist" then change to "remove" when conditionally rendered. It is changing in state from true to false and back to true but the button wont change in the Btn component!

Here is where it is rendered in app:

```
{filteredApplicants.map((applicant) => {
    return(<div className='applications'> <ul >
      <li  className='applicant-li' key={applicant.id}> <h5>{applicant.name} - {applicant.position}</h5>
        <p></p>
        <Btn onFavorite={() => this.onFavorite(applicant)} shortlist={this.state.showShortlist} />
      </li></ul> </div>
    )
  })}
```

Here is state and the function in app:

```
         searchField:'',
          saved:[],
          positions:[],
          showShortlist: true
      }
    }
onFavorite = applicant => {
  const { saved, showShortlist } = this.state; 
  console.log(showShortlist)
  if(this.state.saved.includes(applicant)){
    this.setState({showShortlist:!showShortlist})
  } else
   this.setState({
    saved:[...saved, applicant]})
}
```

Here is the btn component:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';

class Btn extends Component{
    constructor({shortlist}){
        super({shortlist})
    }
    render(){

        const remove = <button>Remove</button> 
        const add = <button>Shortlist</button>  
        console.log(this.props.shortlist)
        return(

            {shortlist:true} ? <button onClick={this.props.onFavorite}>Remove</button>:<button>Shortlist</button>  
        )
    }
}

export default Btn;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a correction on your render method, it should be like:

```
    render() {
      const {shortlist, onFavorite} = this.props;
      return (<button onClick={onFavorite}>{shortlist ? 'Remove' : 'Add Favorite'}</button>);
    }
```

Also, your onFavorite method should be like:

```
onFavorite = applicant => {
  const { saved } = this.state; 
  const index = saved.indexOf(applicant);

  if(index === -1) {
   this.setState({
    saved: [...saved, applicant],
   });
  } else {
    saved.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({saved});
  }
}
```

And each button on your map should be passing different props:

```
{filteredApplicants.map((applicant) => {
return (<div className='applications'> <ul>
  <li className='applicant-li' key={applicant.id}> <h5>{applicant.name} - {applicant.position}</h5>
    <p></p>
    <Btn onFavorite={() => this.onFavorite(applicant)} shortlist={this.state.saved.includes(applicant)} />
  </li></ul> </div>
)
})}
```

Comment: it takes 2 clicks for the button to change to shortlist

Comment: the first click sets the value to true(even though it is already true) then the second click renders the remove btn

Comment: My guess is that on your first click, you don't have the applicant on inside your saved obj in your state, so your first click ends up in the else in your onFavorite method. 
Starting from the second click, your state will have the applicant, so the 'if' on onFavorite will be equal to true and the remove button will be shown.

Comment: I will edit my first response and add some modifications to correct this behavior.

Comment: Thank you for the update. However it is changing all of the buttons not just the one clicked

Comment: Oh I see... I will make more changes.

Comment: I've made changes on the render and onFavorite methods, please be sure to check on them.

Comment: Thank you!
also is this how to remove if clicked again?
else {
        this.setState({
          saved: this.state.saved.slice(applicant)

        }

Comment: I changed your onFavorite method on my first answer, so now it is removing the applicants in the else. If my answer helped you, please be sure to upvote it and mark it as accepted, thanks! :)

Comment: unfortunately this did not resolve the removing issue

Comment: What happens? Is there any errors? I made one more change to your render method, please apply it. Also, be sure to double check if you applied all my changes to your code.

Comment: My apologies, still relatively new to the site. But nothing changes when it is clicked a second time. Im monitoring in the console and there is no updating state

Comment: Here I have made a working fiddle, solving your problem https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/304973/
You can use this code as a base to try and make it work on your environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
{shortlist:true} ?
```

doesn't mean anything. You're passing this.props.shortlist as a boolean. true:true is not valid anything